# What is the Javascript equivalent of this jQuery line of code using .css?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

How do I turn this line of jQuery:

```
var newFont = jQuery('h1').css('font-family');
```

into modern JS.
Thought something like this would work:

```
let newFont = document.querySelectorAll('h1').style.fontFamily = "Montserrat, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif";
```

but instead get error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined`

Comment: In short, use `document.querySelector` for one element, `querySelectorAll` for multiple. There is no bulk update methods like in jQuery; you can use something like `querySelectorAll('h1').forEach(element => element.style.fontFamily = '...')` to update multiple.

Comment: That's because `querySelectorAll` will return an iterator. (You can think of it as a array, although it is not). You must cycle through the elements of the iterator and apply `style.fon...` to each element. jQuery functions return especial objects that allow you to apply methods to all elements of the query result calling it just once. The same doesn't happen in plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys! For some reason, now I get `TypeError: el.style.fontFamily is not a function` when I do that. Which I'm confused about b/c it seems like its selecting the correct and same h1 elements as the jQuery code does.

Comment: But it is really not a function, it is a property. You had this bit right in your exemple.  `...style.fontFamily = "Montserrat, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif";`

Comment: Woww duh smh I was doing it completely wrong haha thanks for your help!